# ASP.NET EF has a Route Model Binding, as in Laravel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, laravel, entity-framework

After Laravel, I try to find the same functionality in every framework.
Right now I'm switching to ASP.NET, but I'm worried that I can't use something as handy as Route Model Binding. It's so easy to do CRUD or implement auth Policy. Is there something like that in NET?
For example:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function delete(User $user)
    {
       $user->delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRUD controller pattern in .NET looks like this:

```
class UserController : Controller
{
    MyDbContext db;
    public UserController(MyDbContext db)
    {
       this.db=db;
    }
    public async Task Delete(User user)
    {
       db.Users.Remove(user);
       await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Entities don't have a reference to the database in EF.  They are Plain-Old-C#-Objects (POCOs), so you need to use DI to inject an instance of your DbContext.

[Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is a separate matter, see especially [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).